# Find $n$ when given $12.3 + 16.4(n-1) - 4.1\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{5}\right\rfloor $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Pardon me if this question has been posted incorrectly here. My question is pretty simple.

I am designing a timer in Arduino and the number of counts required to go for $n$ number of seconds vary as following

$$\text{count} = 12.3 + 16.4(n-1) - 4.1\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{5}\right\rfloor  $$

I am given the value of $\text{count}$. From this equation how can I frame an exact equation that can give me the $\text{seconds}$ value, i.e., the exact value of $n$ by resolving the integer-part factor that comes in the last term.

Comment: The inverse is likely to be very difficult to formulate precisely; your best bet is probably to start by removing the int() relation (yielding a linear equation that's easily invertible) and then search in the vicinity of the $n$ you get out of your approximate inversion to find the precise value.  Given the relative magnitude of the difference between the terms in $n$ you may even be able to explicitly prove that the approximation is exact.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki : yaa this is my best try to make the difference smaller. But the readings i get from Arduino are this way only.

Comment: Is n supposed to be an integer?

Comment: yes, n is the number to be feed to a register in arduino

Answer (score 1):

Write $n-1 = 5 k + j$ where $0 \le j < 5$, so $\lfloor \dfrac{n-1}{5} \rfloor = k$.  Then $count = 12.3 + 16.4 (5k + j) - 4.1 k$.  Solve for $k$:
$$ k = \dfrac{10\; count - 123 - 164 j}{779}$$
which must be an integer in the range
$$ \dfrac{10\; count - 123}{779} \ge k > \dfrac{10\; count - 943}{779}$$
Now (if you're not requiring $n$ to be an integer) there may be two integers
in this range, e.g. if $count=246$ we could have $k=3$, $j=0$, $n=16$ or 
$k=2$, $j=4.75$, $n=15.75$.  But if $n$ is required to be an integer, $j \le 4$, and there can be at most one integer $k$ with
$$ \dfrac{10 \; count - 123}{779} \ge k \ge \dfrac{10 \; count}{779} - 1 $$
However, there may be none.

Comment: How do i decide upon the value of j ?

Answer (score 1):

Reverse engineering the formula and pretending that the `int` function has no effect works like this:

$$\begin{align}\text{count} &= 12.3 + 16.4(n-1) - 4.1\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{5}\right\rfloor\\
\text{count}-12.3&=(n_{\text{estimate}}-1)\left(16.4-\frac{4.1}5\right)\\
\frac{\text{count}-12.3}{16.4-\frac{4.1}5}&=n_{\text{estimate}}-1\\
n_{\text{estimate}}&=\frac{\text{count}-12.3}{16.4-\frac{4.1}5}+1\end{align}$$

I get all values of $n$ back as follows:

```
n   count   n estimate
1   12.3    1
2   28.7    2.052631579
3   45.1    3.105263158
4   61.5    4.157894737
5   77.9    5.210526316
6   90.2    6
7   106.6   7.052631579
8   123     8.105263158
9   139.4   9.157894737
10  155.8   10.21052632
11  168.1   11
12  184.5   12.05263158
13  200.9   13.10526316
14  217.3   14.15789474
15  233.7   15.21052632
16  246     16
17  262.4   17.05263158
18  278.8   18.10526316
19  295.2   19.15789474
```

This demonstrates that we could (with a multiplication by $\frac 55$) use

$$n=\left\lfloor\frac{5\cdot \text{count}-61.5}{77.9}\right\rfloor+1$$

and nothing would be lost.

Comment: A side note: if we get $\text{count}$ in integer-only increments, we would need to use a different rounding technique in the final formula, as "floor" would then be incorrect for many values.  I suspect that "round to nearest integer" would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be a downer but it doesn't exist. Don't worry though, I put might best effort in and got you a solution.
$$count=A+B \cdot (n-1)-C \cdot int \left({{n-1} \over 5}\right)$$
partially solve...
$${{count-A} \over C}={B \over C} \cdot (n-1)-int\left({{n-1} \over 5}\right)$$
$${{count+B-A} \over C}={B \over C} \cdot n-int\left({{n-1} \over 5}\right)$$
You said you know the value of count, so we'll just transform the variable to $Y(n)$
$$Y={B \over C} \cdot n-int\left({{n-1} \over 5}\right)$$
Now, if you haven't noticed already, every time the $int(arg)$ ticks up, the graph of this function will move down 1 unit in a discontinuous fashion. The slope of this equation is ${B \over C}$. Sadly this slope is positive, so the graph is not invertible, you can't get unique values of n from unique values of Y. The periodicity of the jumps is once every 5 seconds displaced one unit to the right. Using the formula for slope, we find that the Y distance covered in this time frame is equal to 20 units, or 4 units per second. So the recovery time after each jump is a quarter of a second. During this "recovery" time, the previous period and current periods Y values overlap, thus the solution to this problem is not a function. However, for 4.5 out 5 seconds the solution is a function. Invert the slope, and we find the solution should have a slope of 1/4 and will move one unit to the right every 20 units. The displacement is 5 units.
As an equation...
$$x(Y)=Y-int \left({{Y+15} \over {20}} \right)$$
$$n(Y)={1 \over 4} \cdot \left({Y} \right)-{1 \over 4}$$
What does it mean? n(Y) is seconds given in Y, substitute for your count value. x(Y) incase you want to graph. For 4.5 out of 5 values given, you'll get a solution. Its for all intents and purposes 90% solved!
Edit: This was wrong for a couple of minutes

Comment: This is very confusing...  Any reason you didn't just solve for $n$, as that is the desire of the OP?

Comment: @abiessu You seemed to have skimmed. n(Y) is n as a function of $Y=(Count+B-A)/C$. Also you fail to provide proof of your answer you just give it.

Comment: No, I read the whole thing, and your function does not (directly) demonstrate $n$ as a function of $\text{count}$.  I think it would help to show a picture instead of most of the discussion about a graph...  But, good suggestion that I add some algebraic manipulation to show how I got my formula, thank you.

Comment: @abiessu fair point, I solved it that way because I assumed Op might have more than one equation to solve. In which case manipulating symbols is the best way to get to a solution.  Your new solution, is good.

Comment: what i did: Y = (count+4.1)/4.1.   Hence, n = Y/4 + 1/4. I think it should be +1/4 and not -1/4. Then too i am not getting difference of 1/4.    10 - 10 ;    15- 14.75    20 - 19.50    25 - 24.25.